# A question about comparing List<T>

Tags: c#, .net

i have two lists:

```
List<comparerobj> list_c = new List<comparerobj>();
List<comparerobj> list_b = new List<comparerobj>();
```

i'm filling lists somehow

then i'm trying to find elements in list_b which list_c doesnt contain:

```
foreach (comparerobj b in list_b)
{
    bool lc = !list_c.Contains(b);
    if (lc != true)
    {
        data.Add(b);
    }
}
```

but for any b i'm getting that lc = true. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you have a non-double negative bool? Surely it's going to make it confusing (I had to re-read it 3 times).

Comment: Same... also for comparing it with true, or... false as it is the negative comparator.

Comment: at begining it was easy to read. then i find that this code snippet dont work and made it that confusing. sorry.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove items from one list in another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745544/remove-items-from-one-list-in-another)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How your objects are compared? By default .NET framework compares objects by references. For Example if you create following class:

```
class A
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and follwing code

```
A a1 = new A() { Name = "a" };
A a2 = new A() { Name = "a" };
```

then you will find that these objects are different.

You need to override `Equals` method for .NET Framework to treat above objects as equal.

Comment: thanks. i think you find my mistake. now i'm gonna check msdn for code example of overriding it.

Answer (score 11):

This is kinda' a peeve, but lose the temporary bool.  It's not a non-doublenegative, and it's confusing:

```
foreach (comparerobj b in list_b)
{
    if (list_c.Contains(b))
    {
        data.Add(b);
    }
}
```

Now that you see the simplified logic, it's clear that you're only adding items that are in both lists.  A single negative might be useful here:

```
foreach (comparerobj b in list_b)
{
    if (!list_c.Contains(b))
    {
        data.Add(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sometimes intermediaries are good, in this case they made the code confusing. +1

Comment: I also feel like mentioning, after glancing at this, that you'd be in much better shape if list_c became hashset_c.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using .NET 3.5 this is simple:

```
list_b.Except(list_c);
```

If that's still not calculating equality correctly, the 2nd parameter to [`Except()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) is an `IEqualityComparer<T>` which you can then use to compare your objects however you wish, or you could just override `Equals()` for your `compareobjs`.

If you want to put the values into a new list (which is what I gather from the `data` variable), you can simply do this:

```
var data = list_b.Except(list_c).ToList();
```

#### Edit:

You mention that it doesn't work, and this is likely because you haven't overridden `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` to determine value equality. The easiest way to get your example working is to use implement the `IEquatable<T>` interface on your `CompareObj`:

```
public class CompareObj : IEquatable<CompareObj>
{
    public bool Equals(CompareObj other)
    {
        // example equality, customize for your object
        return (this.ExampleValue.Equals(other.ExampleValue));
    }
}
```

More information can be found on MSDN: http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2009/03/25/how-to-use-linq-methods-to-compare-objects-of-custom-types.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You've inverting the boolean twice. Once on the first line when you do `!list_...` and once on the second when you do `lc != true`.

Try this instead:

```
bool itemExistsInC = list_c.Contains(b);
if (!itemExistsInC){
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using the ! operator twice. 
Also, you don't need to explicitly delcare the bool, in this context.
Try this:

```
foreach (object b in list_b)
{
    if (!list_c.Contains(b))
    {
        data.Add(b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using linq

```
list_b.Except(list_c).ToList().ForEach(data.Add);
```

> but for any b i'm getting that lc =
>   true. what am i doing wrong?

One or more of the following:

- Your sets are entirely different.
- comparerobj needs to overload the Equals() method
- The logic you are using is confusing and doesn't work as intended.

If you only want elements in list_b that are not in list_c:

```
foreach (comparerobj b in list_b)
{
    if (!list_c.Contains(b))
    {
        data.Add(b);
    }
}
```