# Remove items from one list in another

Tags: c#, .net, list

I'm trying to figure out how to traverse a generic list of items that I want to remove from another list of items.

So let's say I have this as a hypothetical example

```
List<car> list1 = GetTheList();
List<car> list2 = GetSomeOtherList();
```

I want to traverse list1 with a foreach and remove each item in List1 which is also contained in List2.

I'm not quite sure how to go about that as foreach is not index based.

Comment: You want to remove items in List1 which are also in List2?

Comment: You need to remove items from list1 and add them to list2 or something else?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477633/a-question-about-comparing-listt

Comment: What should happen if you have list1 = { foo1 } and list2 = { foo1, foo1 }. Should all copies of foo1 be removed from list2, or just the first?

Comment: -1 - I have downvoted every answer in this question because I *thought* they were all wrong, but it appears the question is just asked horribly. Now, I can't change them - apologies. Do you want to remove the items from `list1` that exist in `list2`, or do you want to remove the items from `list2` that exist in `list1`?  At the time of this comment, each answer provided will perform the latter.

Comment: @John Rashch, you should be a little less trigger happy on those downvotes. Some of the answers are fairly conceptual and only demonstrate how to achieve what the OP wants without even relating to the lists mentioned in the question.

Comment: @John Rasch: I have to agree with João - if there is a minor problem with an answer but it is otherwise a good suggestion then point it out in a comment. An otherwise correct answer shouldn't be downvoted because of a small error, as long as the principle is correct. And when you downvote, explain why in a comment as otherwise it leaves people confused as to why their answers have been downvoted. When I first read the question I made the same error and got it the wrong way round, but two people were kind enough to point out my mistake so I fixed it.

Comment: @Mark - you're right, my fault entirely - that's why I put the comment up here explaining what happened, I was searching for a previous answer I had already had to a similar question in the meantime after my voting and was going to leave comments after I found it - turns out that is not the best process for this!

Answer (score 500, accepted):

You can use [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx):

```
List<car> list1 = GetTheList();
List<car> list2 = GetSomeOtherList();
List<car> result = list2.Except(list1).ToList();
```

You probably don't even need those temporary variables:

```
List<car> result = GetSomeOtherList().Except(GetTheList()).ToList();
```

Note that `Except` does not modify either list - it creates a new list with the result.

Comment: Minor point, but this will produce an `IEnumerable<car>`, not a `List<car>`. You need to call `ToList()` to get a list back. In addition, I believe it should be `GetSomeOtherList().Except(GetTheList()).ToList()`

Comment: You will also need `using System.Linq;` if you didn't have it before.

Comment: I've added using System.Linq but i still can't access Except. But in my case I am using ArrayList. Any ideas on how to make it work with ArrayList?

Comment: Note: list1.Except(list2) will not give same result as list2.Except(list1). The last worked for me.

Comment: Just be careful when using `Except` as this actually performs a **set** operation, which distincts the resulting list. I was not expecting this behaviour as I am using a `List`, not a `HashSet`. [Related.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975944/except-has-similar-effect-to-distinct)

Comment: How come this is the right answer? Sure this might give you what you want in your context, however, "Remove items from one list in another" is certainly not equivalent to a set difference operation, and you should not misinform people by accepting this as the right answer!!!!

Comment: I need to do for a readonly property of a class, so this won't work because it needs to set the collection

Answer (score 51):

You don't need an index, as the `List<T>` class allows you to remove items by value rather than index by using the `Remove` function.

```
foreach(car item in list1) list2.Remove(item);
```

Comment: +1, but IMO you should use brackets around the `list2.Remove(item);` statement.

Comment: @sr pt: I always use brackets on statements that appear on another line, but not on single-statement blocks that I can/do place on the same line as the flow control statement.

Comment: As long as you're consistent, it doesn't matter if you use brackets or not.. IMO :)

Comment: @Adam: I agree, but maybe I'd not make it a one-liner. I actually prefer your solution to the most-voted one, too - it's simpler and easier to read right, which is always a plus.

Comment: Agreed -- I like this better because it mutates the existing list as opposed to creating a new one, and I would also not make it one-liner.

Comment: This is not an elegant solution. Use .Except() (see the answer)

Comment: @uriz: Disregarding the qualifications of what would be elegant, this is the only answer that actually does what the question *says* (removes the items in the main list); the other answer creates a *new* list, which may not be desirable if the list is being passed in from a different caller that is expecting it to be modified instead of getting a replacement list.

Comment: @adam-robinson you are right, but i am not sure the question was going in this direction (not creating another list...)

Comment: @uriz: I'd say you're probably right based upon which answer was accepted, but since SO is about more than just answering the question for the person who asked it (it's also about making a knowledge base that others can search for answers), I wanted to answer in a way that answers it the way it was asked.

Comment: @uriz @AdamRobinson since we're discussing elegant solutions... `list1.ForEach(c => list2.Remove(c));`

Comment: "elegant" should mean "the developer stuck maintaining this code will find it simple and easy to understand," which is why this is the best answer.

Answer (score 32):

In my case I had two different lists, with a common identifier, kind of like a foreign key.
The second solution cited by **"nzrytmn"**:

```
var result =  list1.Where(p => !list2.Any(x => x.ID == p.ID && x.property1 == p.property1)).ToList();
```

Was the one that best fit in my situation.
I needed to load a DropDownList without the records that had already been registered.

Thank you !!!

This is my code:

```
t1 = new T1();
t2 = new T2();

List<T1> list1 = t1.getList();
List<T2> list2 = t2.getList();

ddlT3.DataSource= list2.Where(s => !list1.Any(p => p.Id == s.ID)).ToList();
ddlT3.DataTextField = "AnyThing";
ddlT3.DataValueField = "IdAnyThing";
ddlT3.DataBind();
```

Comment: ou never explained what DDlT3 was

Answer (score 25):

I would recommend using the [LINQ extension methods](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020103729/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/021809-1.aspx).  You can easily do it with one line of code like so:

```
list2 = list2.Except(list1).ToList();
```

This is assuming of course the objects in list1 that you are removing from list2 are the same instance.

Comment: It removes duplicates as well.

Answer (score 20):

```
list1.RemoveAll(l => list2.Contains(l));
```

Comment: a.k.a. "totally-impure" :-)

Comment: What wrong with it. It looks better then creating another list using Except. Especially when both lists are very small.

Comment: Since both list methods are `O(N)`, this will lead to `O(N^2)` which might be an issue with large lists.

Answer (score 15):

You could use LINQ, but I would go with `RemoveAll` method. I think that is the one that better expresses your intent.

```
var integers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

var remove = new List<int> { 1, 3, 5 };

integers.RemoveAll(i => remove.Contains(i));
```

Comment: Or even simpler with method groups you can do - integers.RemoveAll(remove.Contains);

Comment: does this solution faster than the LINQ Except method? or use less ressources?

Answer (score 10):

Solution 1 : You can do like this :

```
List<car> result = GetSomeOtherList().Except(GetTheList()).ToList();
```

But in some cases may this solution not work. if it is not work you can use my second solution .

Solution 2 :

```
List<car> list1 = GetTheList();
List<car> list2 = GetSomeOtherList();
```

we pretend that list1 is your main list and list2 is your secondry list and you want to get items of list1 without items of list2.

```
 var result =  list1.Where(p => !list2.Any(x => x.ID == p.ID && x.property1 == p.property1)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

As `Except` does not modify the list, you can use [ForEach](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach) on `List<T>`:

```
list2.ForEach(item => list1.Remove(item));
```

It may not be the most efficient way, but it is simple, therefore readable, and it updates the original list (which is my requirement).

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be quick to convert list A to a dictionary and then foreach the second list and call `DictA.Remove(item)` otherwise I think most solutions will cause many iterations through list A either directly or under the covers.

If the lists are small, it probably won't matter.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have two different list with different DataModals

```
List<FeedbackQuestionsModel> feedbackQuestionsList = new();

List<EmployeesFeedbacksQuestionsModel> employeeQuestionsList = new();

var resultList = feedbackQuestionsList.Where(p => !employeeQuestionsList.Any(x => x.Question == p.Question)).ToList();
feedbackQuestionsList = resultList.ToList();
```

Answer (score -5):

Here ya go..

```
    List<string> list = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" };
    List<string> remove = new List<string>() { "2" };

    list.ForEach(s =>
        {
            if (remove.Contains(s))
            {
                list.Remove(s);
            }
        });
```

Comment: -1. This will throw an exception after the first item is removed. Also, it's (generally) a better idea to traverse the list to *remove*, since it's usually smaller. You're also forcing more list traversals doing it this way.