# Except has similar effect to Distinct?

Tags: c#, linq

I just discovered that `Except()` will remove all elements in the second list from the first, but it also has the effect that it makes all elements in the returned result distinct.

Simple way around I am using is `Where(v => !secondList.Contains(v))`

Can anyone explain to me why this is the behavior, and if possible point me to the documentation that explains this?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The documentation for the [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) function states:

> Produces the set difference of two sequences by using the default equality comparer to compare values.
>
> The set difference of two sets is defined as the members of the first set that do not appear in the second set.

The important word here is **set**, which is [defined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(computer_science)) as:

> ...an abstract data structure that can store certain values, without any particular order, and no repeated values...

Because `Except` is documented as a set-based operation, it also has the effect of making the resulting values distinct.

Comment: Well that makes a little more sense.  Been way to long since I took set math.  Thanks.

Comment: @Stephan - Though, I have to say, the documented behaviour does feel a little weird to me given that `IEnumerable<T>` is a sequence and not a set, so to have a general-purpose extension method for a sequence have set semantics is somewhat strange. But then again, I guess the alternative of having an `Except` method from `IEnumerable<T>` have sequence semantics and one from `ISet<T>` have set semantics is even worse, as `ISet<T>` inherits `IEnumerable<T>` and thus the semantics would differ depending on how the extension method was bound by the compiler.

Comment: @Greg, Mono seems to get this [wrong](http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/trunk/mcs/class/System.Core/System.Linq/Enumerable.cs#l794) (this is actually the second Mono Enumerable bug I've found through StackOverflow).  It returns elements from first as many times as they appear.  My question is, if it's a set difference, why does the documentation show Enumerable.Except preserving the order of first's elements (it also says it returns "A sequence")?  Sets don't preserve order.  Is Enumerable.Except guaranteed to?

Comment: @Matthew - My guess is that for small sequences as in the docs that order might be preserved as sets are often implemented with a hybrid approach, using a list for small capacity and converted to a bucket implementation as the capacity grows, to give good performance in both cases. But I'd consider that to be an implementation detail rather than a contract, and I wouldn't rely on the output of `Except` being in any particular order as the documentation doesn't state that it will be, and implies that it isn't.

Comment: @Greg I have to agree that it feels strange.  That's what threw me off.  Calling `Except` on an IEnumerable I incorrectly assumed it would just enumerate and remove values that matched in the second list.  I didn't really expect for it to alter the purpose of the enumerable into a set.

Answer (score 10):

You wrote:

> Simple way around I am using is `Where(v => !secondList.Contains(v))`

When you do this, there is still Distict done with `secondList`.

For example:

```
var firstStrings = new [] { "1", null, null, null, "3", "3" };
var secondStrings = new [] { "1", "1", "1", null, null, "4" };
var resultStrings = firstStrings.Where(v => !secondStrings.Contains(v)); // 3, 3
```

I created an extension method to have no distinct at all. Examle of usage:

```
var result2Strings = firstStrings.ExceptAll(secondStrings).ToList(); // null, 3, 3
```

This is what it does:

[image]

This is the source:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> ExceptAll<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> first,
    IEnumerable<TSource> second)
{
    // Do not call reuse the overload method because that is a slower imlementation
    if (first == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("first"); }
    if (second == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("second"); }

    var secondList = second.ToList();
    return first.Where(s => !secondList.Remove(s));
}

public static IEnumerable<TSource> ExceptAll<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> first,
    IEnumerable<TSource> second,
    IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer)
{
    if (first == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("first"); }
    if (second == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("second"); }
    var comparerUsed = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<TSource>.Default;

    var secondList = second.ToList();
    foreach (var item in first)
    {
        if (secondList.Contains(item, comparerUsed))
        {
            secondList.Remove(item);
        }
        else
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: A faster implementation, based on the comment of DigEmAll

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> ExceptAll<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> first,
    IEnumerable<TSource> second,
    IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer = null)
{
    if (first == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(first)); }
    if (second == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(second)); }


    var secondCounts = new Dictionary<TSource, int>(comparer ?? EqualityComparer<TSource>.Default);
    int count;
    int nullCount = 0;
        
    // Count the values from second
    foreach (var item in second)
    {
        if (item == null)
        {
            nullCount++;
        }
        else
        {
            if (secondCounts.TryGetValue(item, out count))
            {
                secondCounts[item] = count + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                secondCounts.Add(item, 1);
            } 
        }
    }

    // Yield the values from first
    foreach (var item in first)
    {
        if (item == null)
        {
            nullCount--;
            if (nullCount < 0)
            {
                yield return item;
            } 
        }
        else
        {
            if (secondCounts.TryGetValue(item, out count))
            {
                if (count == 0)
                {
                    secondCounts.Remove(item);
                    yield return item;
                }
                else
                {
                    secondCounts[item] = count - 1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[More info](https://www.siepman.nl/blog/except-intersect-and-union-without-distinct) on my blog (also variant for Intersect and Union)

Comment: This is a horribly inefficient option as searching through a list for each item is rather expensive, as is removing items from a list.  The language `Distinct` uses a HashSet, and as a result is *much* more efficient.  You can easily modify it's implementation to yield repeated elements in the source without killing its efficiency.

Comment: I agree with @Servy, both `Contains` and `Remove` are O(_n_) operations and you are doing them in a loop.

Comment: @Servy, i know it is MUCH slower, but the result is different. Your critic makes sense if you have an implementation that is faster and does the same as shown in the image. I am curious to a better solution. How do modify it's implementation to yield repeated elements in the source without killing its efficiency?

Comment: @AlexSiepman It's as trivial as using a `HashSet` instead of a `List` as the data structure.  That's all you need to do.  Note that your implementation is also not correct; you're removing the item from the list when you should simply not.  The meat of the implementation can just be `if(!set.Contains(item))yield return item;`

Comment: @Servy, this wil not produce the same results. If you try the example I used in the image and the code, your option removes all 2's from the list, but one 2 should stay in the result.

Comment: @Servy: for his (I mean Alex's) special implementation of `Except`, he can't use the hashset because otherwise the duplicates in the second list will be eliminated. It's still possible to greatly improve the complexity though, for example by building a dictionary like `<ITEM, NUM.OCCURR>` and decreasing the num of occurrences instead of remove the items from the list...

Comment: @AlexSiepman That's not the functionality described in the OP.  The described functionality is to removed all items from the source that exist in the second sequence, but to not perform the additional operation of making all remaining items from the source distinct.  Regardless, the question isn't asking for an alternate implementation, rather an explanation as to what the `Except` method does and why.  In short, you're answering a question unrelated to what's asked.

Comment: @digEmAll This is a helpfull comment, I added an improved version with a dictionary.

Comment: @AlexSiepman: there's still one bug when you fill the dictionary, you add an element only if already present (if trygetvalue returns true), you forgot `else{secondCounts.Add(item,1);}`

Comment: @AlexSiepman: also, there's still a problem (maybe). The dictionary approach does not account for null items (since dictionary doesn't support null keys); so if you want to consider these values you should add a dedicated variable to keep the count of null items and obviously the necessary checks...

Comment: @digEmAll Thanks again for your comments. I changed to code again based on your suggestions. I didn't used a dedicated  value to replace the null as it is hard to find a generic dedicated value. For example: a nullable Enum. I just added a nullcounter. The code is long now and needs to split for readability. But that comes when I will use it for production.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question - it may be slow for big lists but it does what it's supposed to do

Answer (score 5):

Given `A = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]` and `B = [3]`.

- `A.Except(B);` returns `[1, 2]` as Greg Beech explained in [his response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2975990/361177)
- `A.ExceptAll(B);` from Alex Siepman [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18321594/361177), returns `[1, 2, 2, 3, 3]` (and I find the name ambiguous).
- `A.Where(v => !B.Contains(v))` from OP work around returns `[1, 2, 2]`

I suppose that OP work around is the desired behavior, and this one has not be treated.

The main issue with OP work around is that [`List<T>.Contains(T)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.contains?view=netframework-4.8) is `O(n)` and `Where` is also `O(n)` making the solution `O(n²)` in time (for A and B of equivalent sizes) and `O(1)` in memory.

We can make it `O(n)` in time and `O(n)` in memory by using hash set:

```
// I accept any better name for this method
public static IEnumerable<TSource> ExceptFrom<TSource>(
    IEnumerable<TSource> first,
    IEnumerable<TSource> second,
    IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer)
{
    if (first == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(first));

    if (second == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(second));

    var secondSet = second as HashSet<TSource> ?? // this trick ignore the comparer
                    second.ToHashSet(comparer ?? EqualityComparer<TSource>.Default);

    // Contains is O(1) for HashSet.
    return first.Where(v => !secondSet.Contains(v));
}
```