# Why Except function applying Distinct?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Except has similar effect to Distinct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975944/except-has-similar-effect-to-distinct)

I'm having two `List<String>` like

```
lstOne = { "A", "B", "C" ,"C" ,"C" };
lstTwo = { "A" };

lstResult = lstOne.Except(lstTwo).ToList();
```

Now the expected output is

```
lstReult = { "B","C","C","C" };
```

But the actula result is like

```
lstResult = { "B","C" };
```

Why its so? i've used `Except` , why its applying `Distinct` too?

Answer (score 12):

"Except" is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx) as returning the *set difference of two sequences*.

The set difference by definition is a set. Sets by definition don't have duplicates.

> the expected output is ...

No, the **expected** output is identical to the **actual** output.

If you expect something different, my advice is to adjust your expectations to match the documented behaviour.

Comment: I found this behavior rather surprising the first time I encountered it. Perhaps the method could have been named better.

Comment: Understanding "set difference" requires enough mathematical background to know that sets don't contain duplicate elements. And skimming over the documentation one can easily miss that it's talking about sets, not sequences. I would have made it clear that it returns distinct elements by specifying it something like "Returns all distinct elements from the first sequence that are not part of the second sequence"

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Good point. I'll mention that to the documentation manager next time I see him.

Answer (score 11):

It is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) as returning "A sequence that contains the set difference of the elements of two sequences.". Sets do not have duplicates.

It is perhaps a subtle point, but it functions as per the spec.

If you want the dups:

```
var lstOne = new[] { "A", "B", "C" ,"C" ,"C" };
var except = new HashSet<string> { "A" };

var lstResult = lstOne.Where(x => !except.Contains(x)).ToList();
   // ^^ "B", "C", "C", "C"
```

Comment: Using a HashSet removes the duplicates.  How would you handle this if you were checking for, say, { "C", "C" }?

Comment: @Mike first define what you mean by { "C", "C" } - in terms of set theory, that is identical to { "C" }. If you mean "two instances of `"C"` ", then you need to define whether you mean adjacent (i.e. the ordered sequence), or just count-wise.

Comment: Not sure about adjacency or counts or whatnot.  However, I have a need where, using the above example of a first list with {"A", "B", "C", "C", "C"}, and removing {"C", "C"}, I need to be left with just {"A", "B", "C"}.  Using a HashSet for the second list will leave me with {"A", "B", "C", "C"}, instead.    And, to make matters more complicated, I need to do this on complex types instead of strings.  Hope that explains things a little better.

Answer (score 2):

[MSDN Definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx): "Produces the set difference of two sequences by using the default equality comparer to compare values." --> Difference as set --> each key is unique.