# LINQ Except is not retrieving the duplicates

Tags: c#, linq

I have two list in c#, and I want to retrieve all elements on listaA that are not present in listaB, so I decided to use Except method like the code bellow:

```
List<string> listaA = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "e", "e" };
List<string> listaB = new List<string>() { "e" };

var inter = listaA.Intersect(listaB);
var excep = listaA.Except(listaB).Count();
```

except output -> 4

But my expected output should be 5 since we have two "b", so if in the ListaA we exclude all the elements that are present in listaA, why the output is 4 instead of 5, and how can I put it working as I expect?

Comment: From [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Linq.Enumerable.Except%60%601)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8#remarks) _Only unique elements are returned._

Comment: `var excep = listaA.Count(l => !listaB.Contains(l));` this simple workaround returns an expected result. Linked thread has this answer

Comment: @Pugnatore, I added an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60004491/361177 that may address your specific problem

Comment: thank all of you guys! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `Where` and then get the `Count` of the output:

```
var result = listaA.Where(x =>!listaB.Contains(x));
var newcount=result.Count();
```

Comment: How it's different from my comment above? And answers in existing thread?

Comment: It is not. I was writing the answer and did not see the comments sir.

Comment: This solution is not optimal in time (`O(n²)`) and can be improved by a Space–time tradeoff https://stackoverflow.com/a/60004491/361177