# Except a generic list with another generic list without applying distinct operation

Tags: c#, list, linq, generics, except

In the following code, I expect the result has 2 elements with same values("Item1","Item1") but the `result` has 1 element("Item1"):

```
var list = new List<string>(){"Item1","Item1"}; 
var emptyList = new List<string>();
// I expect the result of follwing line be {"Item1","Item1"} but is {"Item1"}
var result = list.Except(emptyList);
```

Seems `Except()` method return unique values of the result set, How can I get desired value?

Comment: The word "Set" is all over the doc page for `Except()` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=net-7.0). I realize you're using lists, but sets cannot contain duplicates.

Comment: "Produces the set difference of two sequences by using the default equality comparer to compare values." It's right there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0#definition) itself has [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)).

> Produces the set difference of two sequences.

If you read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0#remarks) carefully.

> The set difference between two sets is defined as the members of the first
> set that don't appear in the second set.
>
> This method returns those elements in first that don't appear in
> second. It doesn't return those elements in second that don't appear
> in first. Only unique elements are returned.

Workaround is to use `list.Where(x => !emptyList.Contains(x))`

Also, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975944/except-has-similar-effect-to-distinct) question for more clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following:

`var result = list.Where(s => !emptyList.Contains(s));`

Performance will be worse but whether that matters depends on your dataset.

Comment: If `emptyList` was a `HashSet<string>` the performance should be equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Just mock the [ExceptIterator](https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/Except.cs,79), replace `Add` with `Contains`

```
private static IEnumerable<TSource> ExceptOrdinaryIterator<TSource>(
        IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second)
{
    var set = new HashSet<TSource>(second);
    foreach (TSource element in first)
        if (!set.Contains(element))
            yield return element;
}
```