# Remove items of list from another lists with criteria

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

i have a list of writers.

```
public class Writers{   
    long WriterID { get;set; }
}
```

Also I have two lists of type Article.

```
public class Article{
    long ArticleID { get; set; }
    long WriterID { get; set; }
    //and others    
}
```

so the code i have is:

```
List<Article> ArticleList = GetList(1);
List<Article> AnotherArticleList = AnotherList(2);
List<Writers> listWriters = GetAllForbiddenWriters();
```

I want to remove those records from `ArticleList`, `AnotherArticleList` where `WriterID` matches from `listWriters` `WriterID`. How to do this in LINQ?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

If you've actually got a `List<T>`, I suggest you use [`List<T>.RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx), after constructing a set of writer IDs:

```cs
HashSet<long> writerIds = new HashSet<long>(listWriters.Select(x => x.WriterID));

articleList.RemoveAll(x => writerIds.Contains(x.WriterId));
anotherArticleList.RemoveAll(x => writerIds.Contains(x.WriterId));
```

If you *do* want to use LINQ, you could use:

```cs
articleList = articleList.Where(x => !writerIds.Contains(x.WriterId))
                         .ToList();
anotherArticleList = anotherArticleList
                         .Where(x => !writerIds.Contains(x.WriterId))
                         .ToList();
```

Note that this changes the *variable* but doesn't modify the existing list - so if there are any other references to the same list, they won't see any changes. (Whereas `RemoveAll` modifies the existing list.)

Comment: As articleList and anotherArticleList have Article objects and listWriters has Writers objects, this wouldn't work unless the Equals method was overridden to only compare WriterID with correct casting since it doesn't look like she has a common interface implemented by Article / Writers.

Comment: I think it's possible without creating a HashSet of writerIds. If you take a look at my post below...

Comment: @bitxwise: Yes, it's *possible* - but I think my solution is clearer and will also be more efficient, particularly if there are lots of writers. (I'd personally use `Any` rather than `Exists`, but it doesn't really matter.)

Comment: @Jon - you'd still be iterating through the entire writersList in order to make your HashSet - just to iterate through your HashSet again when applying it against the article lists, so I don't think it's more efficient...As for clearer, perhaps to some degree more intuitive? However, from looking at the code I posted you can determine that it's removing from an article list where the writer exists in the writerList (and the determination is made via WriterID).

Comment: @bitxwise: No, because `Contains` on a HashSet doesn't iterate through it all. It does a hash lookup, which is O(1) instead of O(n). You'd also not have to fetch the property on every Writer on every iteration. In terms of clarity, I think it's better to think of the "banned" writers as a set than as a list as order is unimportant, and we're *finding* them via ID, so that's all we care about.

Comment: Oh right, hash lookup FTW. Well, either way, I think the asker has an appropriate answer =) And I have no idea why I automatically typed the asker's gender with "she"...oi, it's late haha

Comment: +1 for teaching me about `HashSet` - Will definitely try and use that more often now.. I just need to remember about it :) Thanks- as always a great answer.

Comment: @Jon Skeet If i still need the elements of the list is better(Performance wise) to copy them into a new list using list<Article> tempArticleList = new list<Artice>(articleList); then using the remove all on the Templist. or the second way is better. Thanks for your support

Comment: @nayefharb: I'd need to see the exact context, to be honest.

Comment: @JonSkeet  can you take a look                                   https://gist.github.com/anonymous/87b8c5aec00ba38d6135#file-gistfile1-vb

Comment: @nayefharb: Well that creates a temporary collection on each step, then does nothing with it - so it's far from useful context. Consider asking a new question with more context.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I have put the code as an example that i am creating the templist inside a for loop. Anw Thanks for your support i will post a full question with useful context about that soon

Comment: Be aware that the `List<T>.RemoveAll` method is a bit dangerous. In case the predicate throws for some element, which in this case might happen if the list contains a `null` `Article` object, the list might [become corrupted](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/66255 "Not documented that the List<T>.RemoveAll method can corrupt the list").

Answer (score 51):

```
articlesList.RemoveAll(a => listWriters.Exists(w => w.WriterID == a.WriterID));
anotherArticlesList.RemoveAll(a => listWriters.Exists(w => w.WriterID == a.WriterID));
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [Except](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2745558/10634638):

```
List<car> list1 = GetTheList();
List<car> list2 = GetSomeOtherList();
List<car> result = list2.Except(list1).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not really see what is the difficulty you are facing...

Why don't you just filter/remove data from you lists using a simple for loop ?
(Note that a foreach Loop will definitely NOT work if you iterate while editing/changing the iterated object)

```
for (int i = ArticleList.Count -1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < listWriters.Count; j++)
    {
        if (ArticleList[i].WriterId == listWriters[j].WriterID )
            ArticleList.RemoveAt(i);
    }            
}
```

The Backward iteration trick solves the "delete items while iterating" paradigm.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Actually I want a LINQ solution

Comment: I am sooo happy I don't have to write code like that anymore. Good bye `C/C++` days and hello `Linq`  - OMG - My eye balls are bleeding :)

Comment: One doesn't need to write code like that in C++, either. In C++ you have remove_if (introduced a long time ago) and lambdas so the currently accepted answer would be similar if done in C++.

Answer (score -2):

Just a design tip, your class should be called `Writer` (singular form), not `Writers` (plural). Each item in your list represents a single writer, correct?

Comment: You should put this into a comment, because it is not an answer to the question.