# Linq: Remove a list of items from another list of items

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following classes:

```
public class A {
   private List<B> Processes {get;set;}
}

public class B {
   private string C {get;set;}
   private DateTime D {get;set;}
   private DateTime E {get;set;}
}
```

Now, I one of my methods I pass a list of B objects and a A object and want to remove all B objects from A's property Processes:

```
private void RemoveProcessesFromA(A a, List<B> p)
{
   foreach (B process in p)
   {
      a.Processes.Remove(process);
   }
}
```

I'm sure there's an easier way to do that using Linq's RemoveAll method. However, I don't know what to use there as the predicate.

Comment: Note that `RemoveAll` isn't part of LINQ. It's just a method on `List<T>` which has been there since 2.0.

Comment: Please refer this question and answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312437/remove-items-of-list-from-another-lists-with-criteria