# To remove records from a list who's column contains elements of the second list using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

So I have a list of string with values.

```
List<string> toBeExcluded = new List<string>() { "gmail.com", "yahoo.com" };
```

I have a query which gets me a list from the database and one of the column is user email.

```
var user = context.Users.Where(w => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(w.Email));
```

Now I need to exclude those users who have emails containing the values in toBeExcluded. So all records with Email of domain gmail.com and yahoo.com needs to be removed.

I tried this, but it did not work.

```
var toBeSent = user.Where(w => !toBeExcluded.Contains(w.Email));
```

So what am i missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove items of list from another lists with criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312437/remove-items-of-list-from-another-lists-with-criteria)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I took my attempt from that answer but it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var toBeSent = user.Where(w => !toBeExcluded.Any(e => w.Email.EndsWith(e)));
```