# Remove duplicate from string array based on another string array

Tags: c#

I have 2 string arrays.I want to remove all the duplicates from a string[] b based on string[] a. I don't want to alter string[] a. I want to remove strings from string[] b that are common in both string[] a and string[] b

for example

```
a = { "1", "2", "3", "4"};
b = { "3", "4", "5", "6"};
```

the result i am looking for is

```
a = { "1", "2", "3", "4"};
b = { "5", "6"};
```

please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove items of list from another lists with criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312437/remove-items-of-list-from-another-lists-with-criteria)

Comment: And [Remove items from one list in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745544/remove-items-from-one-list-in-another?noredirect=1&lq=1), [How would you do a “not in” query with LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183791/how-would-you-do-a-not-in-query-with-linq)

Answer (score 4):

```
b = b.Where(x => !a.contains(x));
```

Or

```
b.RemoveAll(x => !a.contains(x));
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option on top of what's already been answered:

```
b = b.Except(a).ToArray();
```

Note that [`Except()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Except__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) is a method in System.Linq and returns `IEnumerable`, so in order to reassign the result to `b` you need to call `.ToArray()`.

Comment: `Except` feels more natural +1