# How to remove from one list all the items in another?

Tags: vb.net, linq, lambda

I'm reading a set of rows from a remote database, and a similar set from a local database, and then using RemoveAll to get rid of remote rows that are already present locally...

```
remote_events = (From a In remote.Events
                          Where ...etc...).ToList
local_events = (From a In local.Events
                            Where ...etc...).ToList
remote_events.RemoveAll(Function (ByVal event_row As Remote_Event)
    (From a In local_events Where a.Identifier = event_row.Identifier).Count > 0)
```

but this doesn't seem right to me. I don't think I should be counting things when all I really need to do is check whether a match exists. I've tried various usages of `IsDBNull` and `IsNothing` but get nonsense. I can't use `.Except` (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745544/remove-items-from-one-list-in-another)) because the list elements are not the same type.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is this:

```
    remote_events.RemoveAll(Function(e) local_events.Exists(Function(f) f.Identifier = e.Identifier))
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to do this without visual studio, so I'm not sure if this will work, but I'd suppose you could do something along these lines if what you're trying to do is compare the `Identifier`:

```
    Remote_Events = (From r_evt In Remote_Events
                    Where Not ((From l_evt In Local_Events Select l_evt.Identifier).Contains(r_evt.Identifier))
                    Select r_evt).ToList
```

I hope this helps and at least moves you in the right direction.

Comment: This is best; not to include them in the first place.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't get this to work; the tables are in two different databases.

Comment: I don't understand why tht would make any difference.... That should not have stopped this from working....

Comment: John, sorry to swiz you out of your uptick. Trying this caused an exception whose name I forget, but the gist of it was that I couldn't nest queries on different databases that way. I didn't pursue the matter all that hard; perhaps I should have persisted.

Comment: No worries, Brian. Luckily I get enough upticks from other questions :) - I just wanted to let you know that at this point it should be 2 lists you're dealing with and therefore there should be no DB involvement based upon the way you put it in your question... Either way, so long as you got it working, that's the most important part.