# Remove items from one list in another c# with high performance

Tags: c#, list

I need remove all items step by step from list and add removed items to another list, but I need max effective and hithperformance operation. What is whe best practics?

Comment: The best practice is to search first.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove items from one list in another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745544/remove-items-from-one-list-in-another)

Comment: @wudzik no it doesn't looks like it is an duplicate from your link, because he just want to transfer his items to a second list

Comment: I *think* you want something like: `foreach (var obj in secondList.Where(firstList.Contains)) { removedList.Add(obj); firstList.Remove(obj); }`. Dunno if that's the "most performant" way, though.

Comment: @Corak. Yes, I want something with foreach, but I think for is better?

Comment: -1: The only best practice is to set goal and than measure your code with at least `Stopwatch` or profile if necessary. Performance question better include samples of several versions of the code with corresponding measurements and stated goal. It should not take too long to write 2 versions of the code and compare (if it requires a lot of time for you it may mean that some practice is necessary before solving performance issues).

Answer (score 4):

You could use this code and hope that framework'll do the best for you:

```
public static void MoveItems<T>(List<T> list1, List<T> list2)
{
    list2.AddRange(list1);
    list1.Clear();
}
```

Comment: I think used for oparator, because i need delete one item step bu step, not all items and add this item to another list

Comment: How about HashSet<T>? I need max performance

Comment: @user2588686 showing sample code would go long way in making this question better... How you expect adding extra unrelated collection will speed up copying items between 2 lists (if your original question actually what you need)?

Answer (score 2):

```
list2 = list1.ToList();
        list1.Clear();
```