# Is there an overloaded method for the .Remove that accepts a list of objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am working on an asp.net mvc web application using entity frameork,but i have a question if there is an overloaded method for the `.Remove`, where i can pass a list of objects rather than passing one object only at a time , something such as :-

```
entity.VM.Remove(server.VMs);
```

as currently i have to loop though my Server object and delete the related VM one by one such as :-

```
foreach(var i in server){
entity.VM.Remove(i.VM);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Overload No, but alternative Yes**

```
  RemoveRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
```

The entities need only have the Key filled.  Check the docu on the method before using.

Comment: i can nto find a method called RemoveRane ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Except`

You can use Except:

```
List<car> list1 = GetTheList();
List<car> list2 = GetSomeOtherList();
List<car> result = list2.Except(list1).ToList();
```

You probably don't even need those temporary variables:

```
List<car> result = GetSomeOtherList().Except(GetTheList()).ToList();
```

Note that Except does not modify either list - it creates a new list with the result.

Example take from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745544/remove-items-from-one-list-in-another):