# Linq or Lambda - Remove from List A all items from List B

Tags: c#, linq, list, lambda

As I am a newbie in Linq or Lamdba, I was wondering if there is a way in Linq or Lambda that I can remove items from a list based on another list as shown on the example below:

List A = {A, B, C, D, E, F};

List B = {C, A, E};

Output = B, D,F

Comment: `var output = listA.Except(listB)` or if you really need a list `var output = listA.Except(listB).ToList()`. It's a good idea to learn the methods of the [Enumerable class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: The question is aswered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745544/remove-items-from-one-list-in-another Cheers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Very easily:

```
ListA.Except(ListB)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
 ListA.RemoveAll(i => ListB.Contains(i));
```

Comment: He probably does not want to mutate the list.

Comment: @SLaks He explicitly says he wants to remove from the list in the question :). Though, it *could* be interpreted either way. Both answers are correct