# Remove a range of items from a list without looping

Tags: c#, list, linq, collections

Hi Is there a more ellegant way of doing this must I do the loop is there like a range funciton I could just remove all the items found

Sorry I should have showing how my qry is being inserted.

Btw these are two different entities that I am removing from I hope you get the idea.

```
var qry = db.AssemblyListItems.AsNoTracking().Where(x => 
x.ProductionPlanID == (long)_currentPlan.ProductionPlan ).ToList();

var hasbeenAssembled = db.CompletedPrinteds.AsNoTracking().Where(x =>
x.ProductionPlanId == item.ProductionPlanID).ToList();

var hasbeenFound = db.CompletedPrinteds.AsNoTracking().Where(x => 
x.ProductionPlanId== item.ProductionPlanID).ToList();

foreach (var subitem in hasbeenAssembled )
{
  if(item.ProductionPlanID ==subitem.ProductionPlanId && item.DocumentNo == subitem.DocumentNo && item.DocumentNo == subitem.DocumentNo && item.OutstandingToMake ==0)
    {
      qry.RemoveAll(x => x.ProductionPlanID == subitem.ProductionPlanId && x.DocumentNo == item.DocumentNo && x.ItemCode == subitem.StockCode && item.OutstandingToMake ==0);                   

    }
}

public List<AssemblyListItems>  RemoveDespatchedItems(List<AssemblyListItems> AssemblyItems)
{       
        foreach (AssemblyListItems item in AssemblyItems)
        {
            using (var db = new LiveEntities())
            {
                var hasNotBeenDespatched = db.PalletizedItems.Where(w => w.Despatched != "Not Despatched");
                foreach (var subitem in hasNotBeenDespatched)
                {
               AssemblyItems.RemoveAll(x => x.ProductionPlanID == subitem.ProductionPlanID && x.DocumentNo == item.DocumentNo && x.ItemCode == subitem.StockCode);
                }


            }
        }
        return AssemblyItems;
}
```

I just need to remove the items from the first query hasNotBeenDespatched  from the second query.As could be over 400 items i want it to be efficient as possible.

**Edit 2**
 I am a we bit closer thanks buts its still not removing the items from the removedespatchitems from the assebmittems I do not no why

```
public List<AssemblyListItems> RemoveDespatchedItems(List<AssemblyListItems> AssemblyItems, Int64 ProductionPlanId)
{
   using (var db = newLiveEntities())
   {
            List<PalletizedItems> removeDespatchItems = db.PalletizedItems.Where(w => w.Despatched != "Not Despatched" && w.ProductionPlanID == ProductionPlanId).ToList();

            var itemsDocumentNo = db.PalletizedItems.Select(x => x.ProductionPlanItemID).ToList();        
            foreach (var subitem in removeDespatchItems)  {                 

                AssemblyItems.RemoveAll(x => x.ProductionPlanID == subitem.ProductionPlanID && itemsDocumentNo.Contains(x.ProductionPlanItemID) && x.ItemCode == subitem.StockCode && x.LineQuantity==x.AllocatedQuantity);

        }
    }

        return AssemblyItems;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove items from one list in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745544/remove-items-from-one-list-in-another)

Comment: @JohnLBevan i am asking also for a more elgant way of doing the loop.

Comment: @JohnLBevan  and the entitys are not the same so wont work.

Comment: Ah apologies; close vote retracted.

Comment: Would Except work? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @bUKaneer Dont think so as they are two differnent entity lists.

Comment: It's extremely hard to figure out what you're trying to achieve. Fore example, it's not clear how `RemoveDespatchedItems` is related tot the code above it. Anyway, you shouldn't build a list and then remove items from it. Build it once, excluding items by the same criteria you now use later to remove them. In other words: expand the first `Where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% I get exactly how it should be.

However in general you could use `join` that would result in it being done in the database.  Something like this:

```
var remainingItems = (from ali in db.FUEL_AssemblyListItems
            join completed in db.FuelCompletedPrinteds 
                on new { ali.ProductionPlanID, ali.DocumentNo, ali.ItemCode } equals new { completed.ProductionPlanID, completed.DocumentNo, completed.StockCode }
            join dispatched in db.FUEL_PalletizedItems
                on new { ali.ProductionPlanID, ali.DocumentNo, ali.ItemCode } equals new { dispatched.ProductionPlanID, dispatched.DocumentNo, dispatched.StockCode }
            where (ali.ProductionPlanID == (long) _currentPlan.ProductionPlan
                && ali.DocumentNo == completed.DocumentNo
                && completed.OutstandingToMake == 0
                && dispatched.Despatched != "Not Despatched")
            select ali).ToList();
```

Depending upon the records in the database the join might need to be a outer join which needs a slightly different syntax but hopefully you've got a starting point.

Comment: It also needs to account for the Not Despatched in the other table.

Comment: Added not dispatched however I'm not sure how they should work together as the methods do not appear to call each other however the approach of joining still holds.  Depending upon what wants to be returned the where clause probably needs tweaking.

Comment: it said the join was illegal

Comment: Could you elaborate.  Does it say why it is illegal?  It would also help if you could provide details of the database schema.