# How to Remove elements from one List based another list's element and condition?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

How to remove list items from `list1` which mats condition with `list2` items using LINQ without duplicates

I know how to do it in simple `foreach` way but i want the same using `Linq` style single line code.

How to do it using `Linq`?

> Input list

```
list1 = new List(){new object{id = 40},new object{id = 50},new object{id = 60}}
list2 = new List(){new object{id = 400},new object{id = 50},new object{id = 600}}
```

> Expected Output should from `list1`

`new object{id = 40},new object{id = 60}`

Comment: You are missing a break here (I hope). What are the rules for duplicates?

Comment: If you want to `Remove` items from one `List` you should consider calling the `.Remove()` method instead of the `.Add()` method.

Comment: did you mean to say: "how to EXCTRACT items from list 1 that match condition with list 2" ?

Comment: @bommelding - my comment was more intened to be a joke, because of his wording of the question and his solution - found it hilarious that he is talking about removing items but calling `.Add()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove items from one list in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745544/remove-items-from-one-list-in-another)

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with sample inputs **and expected results based on those sample inputs**.

Comment: now you have a salad of variables. `id`, `key`, `key1`, `key2`.. would you care to clean up?

Comment: @MongZhu you can check now

Comment: @bommelding from list1

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can remove the elements like this:

```
list1.RemoveAll(item => list2.Any(item2 => item.Key == item2.Key))
```

Comment: If the OP is happy then this is OK. But technically RemoveAll() is not Linq.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var list = list1.RemoveAll(l => list2.Contains(l));
```

Answer (score 1):

In other perspective,

```
var list1 = Provider.FillList<SomeType>();
var list2 = Provider.FillList<SomeType>();
list1.RemoveAll(n=> list2.Exists(o=> o.Key == n.Key));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try

```
list1.addRange(list2)
then next line would be a simple list1.Distinct(X=>x.Key1).ToList();
```

OR simples would be

```
list1.Except(list2,IEqualityComparer);
```

You would need to implement the equals method for this to work though.

Another way would be to implement the Union

```
var result = List1.Union(List2, myEqualityComparer);
```

which uses the same logic as the except one, there are a few ways to cheat the endresult using link, most of them inefficient and take long to compute

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this with a Join statement:

```
var l = list1.Join(list2, outer => outer.Key, inner => inner.Key, (inner, outer) => outer);
```

where `outer` is list1 and `inner` is list2. The result is a list comprising all elements with the same `Key`, assuming that `Key` is a property of the elements.

Answer (score 1):

The following code worked for me:

```
var list1 = new List<a> { new a { id = 40 }, new a { id = 50 }, new a { id = 60 } }; 
var list2 = new List<a> { new a { id = 400 }, new a { id = 50 }, new a { id = 600 } }; 
var exceptedItems=list1.Select(x=>x.id).Except(list2.Select(y=>y.id)).ToList();
```

---