# Remove all items that appeas in hashset1 from hashset2

Tags: c#, hashset

I want to remove from `hs2` all items that appear in `hs1`.

```
HashSet<string> hs1 = ...;
HashSet<string> hs2 = ...;
```

For example

```
hs1 = {"a","b","c"}
hs2 = {"a","d","e","f","b"}
```

then I want `hs2` to be:

```
hs2 = {"d","e","f"}
```

I need something like:

```
hs2 = hs2.Remove('all items that exists in hs1...');
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove items from one list in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745544/remove-items-from-one-list-in-another)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ExceptWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.exceptwith) like below.

```
hs2.ExceptWith(hs1);
```

> **ExceptWith** : Removes all elements in the specified collection from the current HashSet object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RemoveWhere` method.

```
HashSet<string> hs1 = new HashSet<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };
HashSet<string> hs2 = new HashSet<string>() { "a", "d", "e", "f", "b" };

hs2.RemoveWhere(x => hs1.Contains(x));
```