# How do I remove the uninteresting words and characters with my script?

Tags: python, string

I can not figure out what I'm doing wrong here. This is just part of my project and I am trying to exclude punctuations and uninteresting_words for my final part of the project.  I can run my script in full but it does not remove punctuation or uninteresting_words.  I have tried turning punctuations into a list but it isn't a list of the contents separated into individual items, it's just a list now with all the characters in it as one list item.  As you can see in the code below, I tried saving `punctuations.split()` as a new variable called char and have tried several ways of if loops and iteration to work through words in file_contents

```
def calculate_frequencies(file_contents):   # file_contents is being passed in through another 
                                            # part of the code that comes before this def
    # Here is a list of punctuations and uninteresting words you can use to process your text
    punctuations = '''!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~'''
    uninteresting_words = ["the", "a", "to", "if", "is", "it", "of", "and", "or", "an", "as", "i", "me", "my", \
    "we", "our", "ours", "you", "your", "yours", "he", "she", "him", "his", "her", "hers", "its", "they", "them", \
    "their", "what", "which", "who", "whom", "this", "that", "am", "are", "was", "were", "be", "been", "being", \
    "have", "has", "had", "do", "does", "did", "but", "at", "by", "with", "from", "here", "when", "where", "how", \
    "all", "any", "both", "each", "few", "more", "some", "such", "no", "nor", "too", "very", "can", "will", "just"]
    
    # LEARNER CODE START HERE
    char = punctuations.split()
    result = {}
    for words in file_contents.split():
      if words == uninteresting_words:
        pass
      if words.isalnum() and words != uninteresting_words:
        if words not in result:
            result[words]=1
        else:
            result[words]+=1
            
    print(result) # this line and the following 2 are just so i can see what how they show up
    print(char)
    print(uninteresting_words)
    
    
    #wordcloud-this part and after is ok and is working as expected with the code that follows 
    cloud = wordcloud.WordCloud()
    cloud.generate_from_frequencies(result)
    return cloud.to_array()
```

Comment: Try `if words in uninteresting_words:`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove items from one list in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745544/remove-items-from-one-list-in-another)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment said you should use
`if words in uninteresting_words:`

I don't think your input text is splitting on special characters on punctuation anyway. list.split() splits on spaces by default. Use `words.strip(punctuation)` to remove the punctuation all together.

You should also not use a docstring (''', the trippple quote) for a string. Use ' or " and escape other characters as needed.

```
def calculate_frequencies(file_contents):   # file_contents is being passed in through another 
                                            # part of the code that comes before this def
    # Here is a list of punctuations and uninteresting words you can use to process your text
    punctuations = "!()-[]{};:'\"\\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~"
    uninteresting_words = ["the", "a", "to", "if", "is", "it", "of", "and", "or", "an", "as", "i", "me", "my", \
    "we", "our", "ours", "you", "your", "yours", "he", "she", "him", "his", "her", "hers", "its", "they", "them", \
    "their", "what", "which", "who", "whom", "this", "that", "am", "are", "was", "were", "be", "been", "being", \
    "have", "has", "had", "do", "does", "did", "but", "at", "by", "with", "from", "here", "when", "where", "how", \
    "all", "any", "both", "each", "few", "more", "some", "such", "no", "nor", "too", "very", "can", "will", "just"]
    
    # LEARNER CODE START HERE
    result = {}
    for words in file_contents.split():
      words = words.strip(punctuations)
      if words in uninteresting_words:
        pass
      else:
        if words not in result:
            result[words]=1
        else:
            result[words]+=1
            
    print(result) # this line and the following 2 are just so i can see what how they show up
    print(punctuations)
    print(uninteresting_words)
    
    cloud = wordcloud.WordCloud()
    cloud.generate_from_frequencies(result)
    return cloud.to_array()
```

That should do it.This was the solution that i needed

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/

Comment: the ''', tripple quotes is how that part is written in the code, that is not my contribution.  i do remember recently learning about docstrings but did not add that part.

Comment: I made an edit on how to remove your punctuation.

Comment: im confused on the words.strip(punctuation) suggestion.  im not sure where that goes.  this is all pretty ew to me still so im learning a lot with each exercise

Comment: sorry, i closed the browser and reopened in and now i see the edit.  im reviewing it now.  thanks

Comment: I put the strip at the beginning of the loop. word.strip(punctuations) will remove any punctuation in the word that exists in the punctuations string.

Comment: got it.  thanks.  It seems that even though ''' is meant for a docstring, it will do the same thing as using " " for setting the string of characters in the variable punctuations